# Persistence of SQL Variables Between Statements Using SET and DECLARE in Perl's DBI

Tags: sql, sql-server, perl, dbi

I am trying to declare/set some variables in SQL-Server using a Perl DBI statement and then use those variables in other DBI statements, but it seems like the variables are not persisting between statement calls.

```
$dbh->do(
    q{
        DECLARE @BOM1 datetime      -- Beginning of Month 1 in the Quarter
        DECLARE @BOM2 datetime      -- Beginning of Month 2 in the Quarter
        DECLARE @BOM3 datetime      -- Beginning of Month 3 in the Quarter
        DECLARE @EOM1 datetime      -- End of Month 1 in the Quarter
        DECLARE @EOM2 datetime      -- End of Month 2 in the Quarter
        DECLARE @EOM3 datetime      -- End of Month 3 in the Quarter

        SET @BOM1 = DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE()) -3,  0)
        SET @BOM2 = DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE()) -2,  0)
        SET @BOM3 = DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE()) -1,  0)
        SET @EOM1 = DATEADD(DAY, -1, @BOM2)
        SET @EOM2 = DATEADD(DAY, -1, @BOM3)
        SET @EOM3 = DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE()), 0) -1
    }
);


(
    $start_of_month_1,
    $start_of_month_2,
    $start_of_month_3,
    $end_of_month_1,
    $end_of_month_2,
    $end_of_month_3
) = $dbh->selectrow_array(
    q{
        SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), @BOM1, 107),
               CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), @BOM2, 107),
               CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), @BOM3, 107),
               CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), @EOM1, 107),
               CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), @EOM2, 107),
               CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), @EOM3  107)
    }
);
```

I get the following error messages:

```
DBD::ODBC::db selectrow_array failed: [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Must declare the scalar variable "@BOM1". (SQL-42000)

[Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Statement(s) could not be prepared. (SQL-42000)
```

If I merge these two statements then everything works fine, but I have many different queries that I want to run and use those declared variables. I could solve this by using the Perl variables I get back, but I wanted to know what I'm doing wrong or if it is possible to do this with the SQL variables.

Edit:
This is the connection string I am using:

```
"dbi:ODBC:driver={SQL Server};server=$server;database=$database;port=$port"
```

Comment: What does your connect string look like? Do you have auto commit set?

Comment: I added the connection string to the bottom of the question. Issue remains the same regardless of auto-commit being set or not.